# How to call Constructors in Java

Tags: java

I have following code in java:

```
// SingleMaltView class
class abc {
    public abc(display p) {
        // display is another class.
    }
}

class sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        abc ob = new abc(); // error
    }
}
```

How to call constructor of `abc` class?

Comment: `new abc(<instance of ‘display’ goes here>)`

Comment: You can use any coding conventions you like in your own code, but when asking for help, I recommend using standard naming conventions. Java class names are written with a capital first letter, so `Abc` and `Sample` and `Display`.

Comment: Learn about Java naming convention. Class names should start with an uppercase value

Comment: `new abc();` *does* call a constructor, your issue is that it tries to call a constructor that *doesn't exist*. When you explicitly declare a constructor for a class the compiler stops providing a free no-args constructor for you. Either you will need to explicitly add a no-args constructor so that you can call it, or you need to provide the parameters required by the constructor that you've defined when you call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor has an argument / parameter, use it:

```
public abc(display p)
//         ↑  here!!!!
```

This means you must provide a `display` object to create the `abc` object, so in the main method you must make something like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    display d = new display(); // assuming display has no-argument constructor
    abc ob = new abc(d);   // NO error! :)
}
```

**NOTES:**

- java objects by convention starts in `UPPERCASE`, so names of files and classes should be `Display` and `Abc` (or `ABC`).
- if you don't put any code into constrctor, dont create it
- java provides a default empty constructor to instantiate your objects when you don't create any.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont provide constructor in a class, compiler inserts by default no arguments constructor but if you have provided then compiler wont insert default constructor. Here you are creating an object of a class in which parameterized constructor is present and you are creating object of class ABC with no parameters so compiler is unable to locate no argument constructor and hence gives error below code can solve this riddle.

```
    public abc()    // another constructor
    {

    }
```

or change creation type

```
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
              Display d =new Display();
              abc ob = new abc(d);   // error
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are calling default constructor which is not there in your **abc class**. rather you have a single parameterized constructor.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    abc ob = new abc();   // error
}
```

And here you are creating an object which has no argument.

So you should pass here something like this,

```
display obj = new display();
abc ob = new abc(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can define a constructor in 2 ways:
(i) Default constructor
(ii) Parametrised constructor

(i)Default constructor syntax: 
  ConstructorName()
  {Statements.. }

(ii)Parametrised constructor syntax: 
  ConstructorName(Parameter/Arguments)
  {Statements.. }

*Syntax to call a constructor
  ClassName reference variable = new TypeOfConstructor()

*To call the variable and method of constructor which defined under the scope, call it by using reference variables.

Note: Constructor doesn't have any return type and access specifier